# Set views folder for ApplicationController in Sinatra without overriding

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have three controllers in my Sinatra App:  the base ApplicationController, and an AuthorsController and BooksController which each inherit from ApplicationController.

My file structure for views is:

```
|-views
|   |
|  books/
|   |
|  authors/
|   |
|  home.erb
```

I have set the views folder for Books with `set :views, "app/views/books"` at the top of the BooksController, and Authors similarly; both work.

The ApplicationController only has one route defined:

```
class ApplicationController < Sinatra::Base

    set :views, "app/views"

    get "/" do
        erb :home
    end

end
```

When I go to "/" it looks for the home view in either the Books folder or Authors Controller, depending on which one comes first in my config.ru file:

```
require_relative './config/environment'

use BooksController
use AuthorsController
run ApplicationController
```

Commenting out the other controllers (or just the `set :views` line within them) makes the "/" route work as expected.  My code is definitely hitting the right method of the right controller; it's just looking for the view in the wrong place.

Comment: Why are you deriving other controllers from `ApplicationController` instead of `Sinatra::Base`? What are you trying to add to all your controllers?

Comment: @Sara Not much:  basically just a `method_override: true`.  I had thought it would make sense to have a parent controller for the whole app, but I see now I was mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

In Sinatra, routes are matched in the exact order that they are defined in your code, so if you implement the same route twice, only the one that comes first will ever be used.

You did not provide a [verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so I cannot be sure what is wrong, but it looks like you did not define any route but "/" and it is supplied in all 3 controllers (1 explicitly and 2 by inheritance). All you did was change where to look for views, so the expected behavior of having BooksController defined first would be that `GET /` results in the app rendering `home.erb` in `app/views/books`.

There is nothing in your post that suggests a reason for creating `ApplicationController` as a base class for your other controllers. You can either just derive all your controllers from `Sinatra::Base` or you can keep `ApplicationController` but remove its `get "/"` method, then derive `HomePageController` from `ApplicationController` and put the `get "/"` method there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187686/discussion-between-thumbtackthief-and-old-pro).